# Matlab - [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt

Tags: sql-server, database, matlab, odbc

I am running several SQL scripts from Matlab. For the last couple of months, there were no problems with it. However, since this week, I am starting to receive the following error:

> Error using database.jdbc.connection/exec (line 53) [Microsoft][ODBC
>   SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt

I have installed my ODBC driver on Matlab correctly, and I run the SQL queries as follows:

```
%  connect
conn = database('connectionName','user','password');

% I actually alter between two queries, but put the same here as an example
for i=1:2

   querynew  = "SELECT * FROM tbl";   

   results   = exec(conn, querynew); % the error is triggered here
   results   = fetch(results);
   Data      = results.Data;

end

close(conn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close the cursor, using `close(results)`:

```
for i=1:2

   querynew  = "SELECT * FROM tbl";   

   results   = exec(conn, querynew); % the error is triggered here
   results   = fetch(results);
   Data      = results.Data;
   close(results);

end
```

https://ch.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/close.html?requestedDomain=true